# In R, if there are multiple TRUE answers, select the first TRUE answer

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that represents a two-year daily time series of temperature for one river. For this river, I would like to know what day of year (`doy`):

1. temperature is sustained greater than or equal to 10 degrees

- sustained is when there are no more dips below 10 until *after* the peak temperature of the year, such as during autumn or winter

2. temperature is sustained less than or equal to 10 degrees

- sustained is when there are no more peaks above 10 until the following year

I run into errors when I try to calculate 2 because there are multiple `TRUE` answers for the code to choose from. I would like to know how I can make the code go with the first `TRUE` answer if there are multiple `TRUE` answers.

Example Dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(dataRetrieval)

siteNumber <- "01417500"
parameterCd <- "00010" # water temperature
statCd <- "00003" # mean
startDate <- "2015-01-01"
endDate <- "2016-12-31"

dat <- readNWISdv(siteNumber, parameterCd, startDate, endDate, statCd=statCd)
dat <- dat[,c(2:4)]
colnames(dat)[3] <- "temperature"

# Visually inspect the time series
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = Date, y = temperature)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

Code for 1 & 2 where 2 is having issues because there are multiple `TRUE` statements to choose from

```
dat %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date),
         doy = yday(Date)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(gt_10 = temperature >= 10, # greater than or equal to 10 degrees
         lt_10 = temperature <= 10, # less than or equal to 10 degrees
         peak_doy = doy[which.max(temperature)], # what doy is max temperature
         below_peak = doy < peak_doy, # is the observed doy less than the peak temperature doy
         after_peak = doy > peak_doy, # is the observed doy greater than the peak temperature doy
         test_above = ave(gt_10, cumsum(!gt_10), FUN = cumsum), # counts number of days above 10 degree threshold
         test_below = ave(lt_10, cumsum(!lt_10), FUN = cumsum)) %>% # counts number of days below 10 degree threshold
  summarise(first_above_10_sustained = doy[below_peak == T & test_above == 14]-13, # answer to 1 
            first_below_10_sustained = doy[after_peak == T & test_below == 14]-13) # answer to 2
```

- To answer 2, the code is looking at those times when temperature is *after* the annual peak temperature (i.e., `after_peak == T`) **and** when temperature has been below the 10 threshold for 14 consecutive days (i.e., `test_below == 14`). The `test_below == 14` is where the error lies because there are multiple times when this occurs. Yes, you could change the threshold of consecutive days to some value > 14 but that is beside the point. How can I get the code to accept the first `TRUE` answer is there are multiple `TRUE` answers?

I have a [similar SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74212908/which-is-first-day-above-and-below-threshold/74213412#74213412) but my answer only works when there is not multiple `TRUE` answers to choose from.

Comment: 1) You don't need an explicit test `below_peak == T`, since `below_peak` already is `FALSE/TRUE`, `below_peak` alone will do the same: 2) to get the first `TRUE` try something like `min(which(below_peak))`. `which` transforms the logical condition into a integer vector where the condition is met, then `min` finds the first of those values.

Comment: @RuiBarradas point noted with regard to not needing the `== T` for `below_peak`. I tried applying the `min(which())` to the `test_below == 14` because that is where the 14 day threshold information lives. It did not answer the question but it did produce a slightly different error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of tricks I would employ here:

1. Create a column that specifies whether the temperature is above or below 10 degrees.
2. Get the `rleid` of this column, which will group all of the consecutive days above or below the threshold of 10 degrees.
3. Find the maximum temperature of each year, and store it in a column.
4. The `rleid` which contains that maximum temperature will be the dates where temperature is sustained > 10 degrees for that year according to your definition
5. Do the same thing with minimum temperatures, but subtract 6 months when calculating the year to group by when calculating the minimum for that year. This will not make a difference to the end result but allows a calculation of the minimum temperature in the winter period:

```r
df <- dat %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(max_temp = max(temperature)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(above_ten = temperature >= 10,
         run = factor(data.table::rleid(above_ten))) %>%
  group_by(run) %>%
  mutate(sustained_hi = max(temperature) == max(max_temp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date - months(6))) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(min_temp = min(temperature)) %>%
  group_by(run) %>%
  mutate(sustained_lo = min(temperature) == min(min_temp)) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(sustained_hi, 'High', 
                        ifelse(sustained_lo, 'Low', 
                               'Unsustained'))) %>%
  select(site_no, Date, temperature, group, run)
```

This results in:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 731 x 5
#> # Groups:   run [27]
#>    site_no  Date       temperature group run  
#>    <chr>    <date>           <dbl> <chr> <fct>
#>  1 01417500 2015-01-01         0.7 Low   1    
#>  2 01417500 2015-01-02         1.1 Low   1    
#>  3 01417500 2015-01-03         1   Low   1    
#>  4 01417500 2015-01-04         2.5 Low   1    
#>  5 01417500 2015-01-05         2   Low   1    
#>  6 01417500 2015-01-06         0.3 Low   1    
#>  7 01417500 2015-01-07         0.2 Low   1    
#>  8 01417500 2015-01-08         0.2 Low   1    
#>  9 01417500 2015-01-09         0.3 Low   1    
#> 10 01417500 2015-01-10         0.3 Low   1    
#> # ... with 721 more rows
#> # i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

And we can see the result by plotting like this:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = temperature, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(limits = c('High', 'Unsustained', 'Low'),
                     values = c('orange', 'gray', 'steelblue')) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

And we can get a nice little data frame of the start and end dates of our sustained high / low temperatures by doing:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(group != 'Unsustained') %>%
  group_by(run) %>%
  summarize(Date = c(first(Date), last(Date)),
            Event = paste('Sustained', first(group), c('Start', 'End'))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-run)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    Date       Event               
#>    <date>     <chr>               
#>  1 2015-01-01 Sustained Low Start 
#>  2 2015-04-28 Sustained Low End   
#>  3 2015-04-29 Sustained High Start
#>  4 2015-07-16 Sustained High End  
#>  5 2015-11-08 Sustained Low Start 
#>  6 2016-03-31 Sustained Low End   
#>  7 2016-05-18 Sustained High Start
#>  8 2016-10-09 Sustained High End  
#>  9 2016-10-23 Sustained Low Start 
#> 10 2016-12-31 Sustained Low End
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that builds off of the original approach to the question and uses parts proposed by @AllanCameron

This works by splitting the annual time series into times **before** and **after** the peak temperature. Then a run-length ID column (`run`) is added. This allows us to determine where the `run` is max for the subset of `run` when the values are `TRUE` in `below_peak` or `after_peak`. We can then extract the first element of `doy`.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date),
         doy = yday(Date)) %>%
  group_by(site_no, year) %>%
  mutate(gt_10 = temperature >= 10,
         lt_10 = temperature <= 10,
         peak_doy = doy[which.max(temperature)],
         below_peak = doy < peak_doy,
         after_peak = doy > peak_doy,
         run = data.table::rleid(lt_10)) %>%
  summarise(sustain_above = first(doy[run == max(run[below_peak])]),
            sustain_below = first(doy[run == max(run[after_peak])]), .groups = 'drop')
```